# Nullable integer values from reader

Tags: c#, sql

how we read integer null values from Sql Data Reader

```
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (reader.Read() == true)
{
    mb.Id = (int)reader["Id"];
    mb.Mem_NA = (string)reader["Mem_NA"];
    mb.Mem_ResAdd4 = reader["Mem_ResAdd4"] == System.DBNull.Value ? null : (string)reader["Mem_ResAdd4"];
    //
   mb.Mem_ResPin = reader["Mem_ResPin"] as  int? ?? default(int);
  // shows the error "Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types."
 }
```

mb.Mem_ResPin cant read from reader

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Mem_Basic] (
[Id]          INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Mem_NA]      VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
[Mem_ResAdd4] VARCHAR (100) NULL,
[Mem_ResPin]  INT           NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Comment: What is `mb.Mem_ResPin` declared as?

Comment: I know we've already had this conversation, but "dapper" would just *make this work* without you banging your head against ADO.NET every step of the way... just sayin' - there's a reason we wrote it... to avoid *exactly* this kind of pain

Comment: @Marc, and I can **fully** attest to why Dapper is the **best** ORM on the market today! And it's free no less!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just convert it, like you do in previous row

```
mb.Mem_ResAdd4 = reader["Mem_ResAdd4"] == System.DBNull.Value ? null : (string)reader["Mem_ResAdd4"];
//
    mb.Mem_ResPin = reader["Mem_ResPin"]== System.DBNull.Value ? default(int):(int)reader["Mem_ResPin"]
```

Comment: shows the eror "Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types."

Comment: see my response for DBNull treatment

Answer (score 9):

I use a generic extension method for all DB casts:

```
public static T? DbCast<T>(this object dbValue)
        where T : struct
    {
        if (dbValue == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        if (dbValue is System.DBNull)
        {
            return null;
        }
        T? value = dbValue as T?;
        if (value != null)
        {
            return value;
        }
        var conv = dbValue as IConvertible;
        if (conv != null)
        {
            value = (T)conv.ToType(typeof(T), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
        return value;
    }
```

It tries to treat every situation we encountered so far. Adjust conditions as needed for you.

Usage:

```
int? value = reader["Mem_ResAdd4"].DbCast<int>()
```

Answer (score 5):

Write a simple wrapper e.g. as an extension method and check for `IsDBNull` inside:

```
public static int SafeGetInt(this SqlDataReader reader, string colName)
{
    var colIndex = reader.GetOrdinal(colName);
    return !reader.IsDBNull(colIndex) ? reader.GetInt32(colIndex) : default(int);
}
```

usage:

```
var result = reader.SafeGetInt(colName);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use  [`SqlDataReader.GetSqlInt32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getsqlint32.aspx) to handle `Nullable<int>`:

```
SqlInt32 resPin = reader.GetSqlInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("Mem_ResPin"));
mb.Mem_ResPin = resPin.IsNull ? (int?) null : resPin.Value;
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe try this extention:

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static T GetSafe<T>(this SqlDataReader reader, string name)
    {
        var value = reader[name];
        return value == DBNull.Value ? default(T) : (T) value;
    }
}
```

and use like this:

```
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            Mb mb = new Mb();
            mb.Id = reader.GetSafe<int>("Id");
            mb.Mem_NA = reader.GetSafe<string>("Mem_NA");
            mb.Mem_ResAdd4 = reader.GetSafe<string>("Mem_ResAdd4");

            mb.Mem_ResPin = reader.GetSafe<int>("ResPin");
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few approaches here. Unfortunately, `DBNull` makes this vexing - the `reader[name]` API returns an `object` that could be your value, or that could be `DBNull.Value` - so you have to check for that (`is`) and handle it. The other approach is to use the `reader.IsDBNull(ordinal)` API, but as you will note : that needs an *ordinal* (column index) rather than a *name*. In either case, you can add things like utility methods to help:

```
static object Read(IDataReader reader, string name)
{
    var val = reader[name];
    return val is DBNull ? (object)null : val;
}
```

then (for example):

```
mb.Mem_ResPin = (int?)Read(reader, "Mem_ResPin")
```

However, again: tools like "dapper" might make this a lot easier for you; a single `Query<T>(tsql, args).SingleOrDefault()` would deal with all of this, including nulls, `Nullable<T>`, and a range of other scenarios.

Comment: This code would result in a cast error on casting to (int?). You first need to unbox to a regular int.

Comment: @MennovandenHeuvel no, you don't. Try it. Worse: unboxing to `int` (rather than `int?`) would actually make it throw a `NullReferenceException` whenever the value is `null` (which is explicitly an expected scenario here)

Answer (score 2):

```
public static class SqlDataReaderExtensions
{
    public static T Value<T>(this SqlDataReader reader, string name, T defaultValue = default)
    {
        var val = reader[name];

        if (val == DBNull.Value)
            return defaultValue;

        return (T)val;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Compare is against `DBNull`.

```
var resPin = reader["Mem_ResPin"];
if(!Convert.IsDBNull(resPin))
  mb.Mem_ResPin = resPin as int?;
else
  mb.Mem_ResPin = new Nullable<int>();
```

Comment: Are you sure `mb.Mem_ResPin` is an `int?` type?